# find whether a zipped file is text or binary without unzipping it

Tags: ruby, rubyzip, ruby-2.3

I'm creating a ruby script which goes through several zip files and validates the content of any xml files within. To optimise my script, I'm using the ruby-zip gem to open the zip files without extracting them.

My initial thought was to use filemagic to determine the MIME-type of the files, but the filemagic gem takes a file path and all I have are these Entry and InputStream classes which are unique to ruby-zip.

Is there a good way to determine the filetype without extracting? Ultimately I need to identify xml files, but I can get away with identifying plain-text files and using a regex to look for the

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the filemagic gem takes a file path

The filemagic gem's `file` method takes a file path, but `file` isn't the only method it has. A glance at the docs reveals [it has an `io` method, too](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-filemagic/FileMagic#io-instance_method).

> all I have are these Entry and InputStream classes which are unique to ruby-zip

I wouldn't say InputStream is "unique to ruby-zip." From [the docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubyzip/Zip/InputStream) (emphasis mine):

> A InputStream inherits IOExtras::AbstractInputStream in order to provide **an IO-like interface** for reading from a single zip entry

So FileMagic has an `io` method and Zip::InputStream is IO-like. That leads us to a pretty straightforward solution:

```
require 'filemagic'
require 'zip'

Zip::InputStream.open('/path/to/file.zip') do |io|
  entry = io.get_next_entry

  FileMagic.open(:mime) do |fm|
    p fm.io(entry.get_input_stream)
  end
end
```